# Google app script copy document page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a template document in Google Docs containing one page. I would like to create a new document with N pages each identical to the one page from the template document.

How can I do this?

Comment: hi, why did you remove your own answer ? it was the right approach, just a bit incomplete... ;-)

Comment: If I remember correctly, my solution stopped working because Google changed the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog) from Henrique, it uses the different doc elements following the definitions [available in the doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_documentapp_elementtype?hl=fr-FR)... you should pick the one you need and add the corresponding routine.

Here is how it goes (code from the original post):

```js
function mergeDocs() {
  var docIDs = ['list-of','documents','ids','you should have somehow'];
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[0]);
  var body = baseDoc.getActiveSection();

  for( var i = 1; i < docIDs.length; ++i ) {
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[i]).getActiveSection();
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
      var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
        body.appendParagraph(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
        body.appendTable(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
        body.appendListItem(element);
      else
        throw new Error("According to the doc this type couldn't appear in the body: "+type);
    }
  }
}
```